# How to get rid of Siteminder authentication in IBM WAS 8.0 and implement custom authentication?

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, siteminder

I've a web application which is configured to use SSO - Siteminder authentication. Now we have developed over own custom authentication code and want it to be implemented instead of using Siteminder. The application is being deployed in WAS 8.0 server which by default is using Siteminder. So even after we changed our code to perform custom authentication I don't know how when deploying it to server it automatically redirects us to SSO login instead of our custom login page.

In my local machine, the same code picks up this newly developed custom authentication and we've tested it too successfully. But when this code is deployed in actual DEV server, it  ignores our custom login module and goes to Siteminder login page. Do I have to set something at the server side to disable SSO ? If so, can anyone tell me how to disable Siteminder at server for my application?

Comment: Is your custom code still using Java security features or have you implemented your own entire security solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the TAI (Trust Association Interceptor) for Siteminder.   You can either disable TAI completely or just the Siteminder Interceptor.  Via Admin Console go to Security>Global Security>Web and SIP Security>Trust Association to make the necessary changes.

HTH

Dan